# How to get an output from JUnit assertEquals() method and put it into a variable?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a JUnit test case here to test a simple class. Basically the class contains just one method called 'sum' that returns the sum of two numbers. To test if this is right I use the following method: `Assert.assertEquals(2, my_object.sum(1, 2));` The result displays in a tab on eclipse, in a section called "Failure Trace". The message says: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<2> but was:<3>`. Is it possible to get this message and put it into a String variable?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because I need to build a web system to evaluate classes using JUnit test cases as a homework and I need to take this message and show it to the final user.

Comment: @AraújoFilho Seriously, talk to your "final" user. Showing him print outs is stupid. Use JUnit to run all your tests; and worst case, take a screen shot of  that run. Using JUnit to just print stuff from methods ... that is like a complete waste of **your** time (and the one of your "final" user).

Comment: @Jägermeister Thank you for your advice. But this application is going to be used by programming students, they will submit their classes in the system, JUnit test case will test their classes and show them the output. This is not waste of my time because that's a requirement. It's exactly what I need to finish the homework and get the best grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Java doc assertEquals will

> Asserts that two objects are equal. If they are not, an AssertionError
>   without a message is thrown. If expected and actual are null, they are
>   considered equal.

You have to catch `AssertionError`  when your condition fails.

Try this code:

```
 @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception{
        String assertionError = null;
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(2,3);
        }
        catch (AssertionError ae) {
            assertionError = ae.toString();
        }
        System.out.println(assertionError);

    }
```

OUTPUT:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<3>

For more info about AssertionError visit java doc : [AssertionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) and [Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)

Comment: Sorry, but what is the point of this? The idea of JUnit tests is to allow for **automated** execution. The whole framework is based on the idea that failing testcases ... throw AssertionErrors; and the framework running all your tests catches them. Sure, you can catch them yourself, but if you are doing that ... you can go the full nine yards and completely throw away all of the Junit testing. Because you just rendered it **worthless**.

Comment: @Jägermeister You are absolutely correct. There is no point in catching the AssertionError. Since the OP has asked this specific question (for his homework), I have answered.

Comment: I got that part; I was simply wondering if there is any deeper meaning that I am missing. Like in: even home work; you would expect that teachers should be asking for "reasonable" things to do; instead of asking students to  use a framework in a completely "broken" way.

Comment: @Jägermeister Hope his teacher explained the use of JUNIT.  May be I need to update my answer, So that other people should not get confused.

Answer (score 5):

`assertEquals` is a `void` method. You cannot put the result to variable. But you can get the exception with `try/catch` block.

```
try{
  assertEquals("foo", "foo1"); //will fail
} catch(AssertionError e){
  String message = e.getMessage();
  //do whatever you want with e
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. Actually this is not going to the catch when the assertEquals fails. The next lines do not execute when it fails.

Comment: My bad, fixed it! The issue is that `AssertionError` does not extend `Exception` bu `Error`. So it's better to catch `AssertionError` as @Unknown suggested.