# Adding base64 screenshot to extendreport 3.1.5 is unsucessful

Tags: java, collections

I want to take base64 screenshot for all the passed and failed screenshots with testNG, below is my code.

private static ExtentReports extent;
    private static Platform platform;
    private static String reportFileName = "ExtentReports-Version3-Test-Automaton-Report.html";
    private static String macPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/TestReport";
    private static String windowsPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\TestReport";
    private static String macReportFileLoc = macPath + "/" + reportFileName;
    private static String winReportFileLoc = windowsPath + "\" + reportFileName;

```
public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
    if (extent == null)
        createInstance();
    return extent;
}

//Create an extent report instance
public static ExtentReports createInstance() {
    platform = getCurrentPlatform();
    String fileName = getReportFileLocation(platform);
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
    htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
    htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.setSystemInfo("Author", "Gladson Antony");
    extent.setSystemInfo("Browser", Browser);
    extent.setSystemInfo("OS", OSName);     
    extent.setSystemInfo("OS Version", OSVersion);
    extent.setSystemInfo("OS Architecture", OSArchitecture);
    extent.setSystemInfo("OS Bit", OSBit);
    extent.setSystemInfo("JAVA Version",System.getProperty("java.version"));        
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    return extent;
}

//Select the extent report file location based on platform
private static String getReportFileLocation (Platform platform) {
    String reportFileLocation = null;
    switch (platform) {
        case MAC:
            reportFileLocation = macReportFileLoc;
            createReportPath(macPath);
            System.out.println("ExtentReport Path for MAC: " + macPath + "\n");
            break;
        case WINDOWS:
            reportFileLocation = winReportFileLoc;
            createReportPath(windowsPath);
            System.out.println("ExtentReport Path for WINDOWS: " + windowsPath + "\n");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("ExtentReport path has not been set! There is a problem!\n");
            break;
    }
    return reportFileLocation;
}

//Create the report path if it does not exist
private static void createReportPath (String path) {
    File testDirectory = new File(path);
    if (!testDirectory.exists()) {
        if (testDirectory.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + path + " is created!" );
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create directory: " + path);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory already exists: " + path);
    }
}

//Get current platform
private static Platform getCurrentPlatform () {
    if (platform == null) {
        String operSys = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        if (operSys.contains("win")) {
            platform = Platform.WINDOWS;
        } else if (operSys.contains("nix") || operSys.contains("nux")
                || operSys.contains("aix")) {
            platform = Platform.LINUX;
        } else if (operSys.contains("mac")) {
            platform = Platform.MAC;
        }
    }
    return platform;
}
```

Below is my listerner class where I take screenshot for each passed test case using Base64 format.

private static ExtentReports extent = ExtentManager.createInstance();
    private static ThreadLocal test = new ThreadLocal();

```
public synchronized void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("Test Suite started!");
}

public synchronized void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println(("Test Suite is ending!"));
    extent.flush();
}

public synchronized void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " started!"));
    ExtentTest extentTest = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
            result.getMethod().getDescription());
    test.set(extentTest);
}

public synchronized void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " passed!"));
    test.get().pass("Test passed");
    try {
        test.get().pass(result.getTestClass().getName() + "." + result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
                MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(TestBase.addScreenshot()).build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
    test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
    try {
        test.get().fail(result.getTestClass().getName() + "." + result.getMethod().getMethodName(),
                MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(TestBase.addScreenshot()).build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public synchronized void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " skipped!"));
    test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());
}

public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println(("onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage for " + result.getMethod().getMethodName()));
}
```

Thanks in advance for the favour!!

Comment: Assert is a utility class that only has static methods. No instance of Assert is ever created. Storing Assert objects in a Map thus doesn't make sense, since there will never be any Assert object. And even then, `Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected)` doesn't return an Assert: it returns void. Storing void in a Map doesn't make sense, especially when the values are supposed to be of type Assert. What you're actually trying to do is very unclear, but what is sure is that your code makes no sense.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863515/how-to-get-an-output-from-junit-assertequals-method-and-put-it-into-a-variable, may be this will help